Downgrading Adobe Commerce to Open Source
What would be the steps to safely downgrade the database of an Adobe Commerce project to Open Source?

This will depend on how much of the feature set of Adobe Commerce were you using and need to be ported to the open source version. For eg. It maybe that you are using features such as Requisition List, then you would have to create a replacement module for it and migrate the data into that database structure. But if you are for eg. not using Company structure or other B2b modules you can just skip migrating that data entirely.
For most of the common tables between open source and commerce you would find that they have replaced entity_id primary key column to row_id .There is an open source script for porting basic feature set common between open source and commerce editions available here - https://github.com/opengento/magento2-downgrade-ee-ce
I have used it for downgrading our commerce instances few times before, so I think it will serve you well to check it out.

Thanks for the answer! I had tried a similar method but I faced a lot of errors... I am trying the scripts in the github you mentioned but I am facing 1 single error, just in the case you know how to fix it https://github.com/opengento/magento2-downgrade-ee-ce/issues/11

You're using a very old version of Magento, for which I do not have an instance rn. I will try to replicate the issue on my end.

Don't worry. I solved them
